# OpenCV VideoWriter and Hardware h264

Tags: hardware, video, opencv, ffmpeg, h264

I'm working on a python/pygame application, and i'm facing some difficulties when I try to capture a video from a usb camera (640x480) to a h264 encoded file, through OpenCV. Everything work fine with other codecs, DIVX or DX50, but I hope to achieve a better FPS using h264 harware encoding.

So i build ffmpeg from source with h264 support, with success (as shown here) :

```
ffmpeg --version
```

> configuration: --arch=armel --target-os=linux --enable-gpl
>   --enable-omx --enable-omx-rpi --enable-nonfree --enable-libx264

```
ffmpeg -codecs | grep "264"
```

> DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
>   (decoders: h264 h264_vdpau ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_omx
>   h264_vaapi )

And then rebuild openCV 2.4.13 from sources. Sadly, I always get this error when I try to use VideoWriter with "H264" or "X264" fourcc :

```
[libx264 @ 0x1fd1250] broken ffmpeg default settings detected
[libx264 @ 0x1fd1250] use an encoding preset (e.g. -vpre medium)
[libx264 @ 0x1fd1250] preset usage: -vpre <speed> -vpre <profile>
[libx264 @ 0x1fd1250] speed presets are listed in x264 --help
[libx264 @ 0x1fd1250] profile is optional; x264 defaults to high
Could not open codec 'libx264': Unspecified error
```

Did someone see what I missed ?

Comment: I don't know what VideoWriter is, but the partial output you provided is from ffmpeg. You need to show your actual ffmpeg command, and the complete output. Unrelated and minor, but `--enable-nonfree` is not needed since you have no other configure options that require it.

Comment: In fact, OpenCV.VideoWriter launch FFmpeg in background, so i can't access nor modify the ffmpeg command-line, as far as I know.

Comment: It is using an invalid or outdated ffmpeg command, but you say it can't be changed, so there may be no proper solution.